# Windows XP CMD properties shortcut

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I changed properties like screen length and buffer size of my `cmd.exe` (in `system32`). I expected changes to last for all instances, but the following is happening:

- any execution from within the system32 folder and from start->run is fine
- any shortcut in the taskbar or anywhere else yields default values for attributes; the screen is smaller than I set and the buffer is default size

This is not expected behaviour. It hinders me from constructing shortcuts where I need them to start a cmd with the sizes I want. What is wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each shortcut uses it's own layout settings stored in a different registry key under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console**. So you need to set the sizes you want for each shortcut.

This can be done manually or through a script (written by you).